# Compression RC table hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, compression

I'm trying to compress RC table was create as follows:

```
create table rc_test(
   a string,
   b string)
stored as rcfile
```

I have another parquet table and I did it by:

```
alter table parquet_test set tblproperties ("parquet.compression"="snappy");
```

What is the `tblproperties` for RC table?

Comment: Any reason you are using RCFILE, not ORC? Are you using Impala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this properties in the same session before insert overwrite table in Hive:

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
```